# Collecting objects in polygons using QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-processing

I received a polygon layer composed of many little objects due to a former vectorizing of a raster (s.image). For further working I want to make buffers. But I do not want to make buffers for each object. Actually, I want to summarize the objects wich have many neighbor objects and which building clusters. Further I want to use the 'concave hull' (k-neighbor) in QGIS and than doing the buffer.

The problem is that to summarize I have to select by free polygon. But it is a big Layer an it would take a long time to do so. So I am searching of a way to do the summarizing automatically.

I was thinking of a selecting like this:
If an object in this layer has more objects as neighbors it will become a melted object.

Is something like this possible?

[image]

Comment: thanks. That was the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

- Aggregate:

> This algorithm take a vector or table layer and aggregate features
> based on a group by expression. Features for which group by expression
> return the same value are grouped together.

or

- Dissolve:

> This algorithm takes a vector layer and combines their features into
> new features. One or more attributes can be specified to dissolve
> features belonging to the same class (having the same value for the
> specified attributes), alternatively all features can be dissolved in
> a single one